# grails 3.0.3 with asset-pipeline-gradle:2.3.8 is not working after unzip the deploy war file

Tags: grails, gradle, asset-pipeline, grails-3.0

1. I create a new grails app
2. I change the asset-pipeline-gradle version to 2.3.8
3. I deploy the application with command

> grails dev war

4. I just run command

> java -jar App.0.1.war

and it works fun, the css js and images all work ok

5. and if i unzip the war file and copy all the files to my custom tomcat fold, the tomcat startup normally, but the css, js can not display

Can anyone help me, the speed me 2 days to reappear the issue

Comment: i have set provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat", no use

Comment: tomcat 8.0.24
jdk 1.8.45

Comment: Why not put the WAR file into Tomcat's webapps directory?

Comment: same issue. find a resolution yet?

Comment: Possible similar issue *"Asset pipeline links missing cache digest names"* (specific to Grails 3.0.3) at: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to issues from [asset-pipeline](https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/issues/267) and [grails-core](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9151), you can specify the asset-pipeline verion in build.gradle

> runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:**3.0.1**"

or wait for grails 3.0.6

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a grails 3 or asset-pipeline bug. I've been having the same problem with 3.0.3 and 3.0.4, so I ended up opening https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9151 (would have simply commented on your question, but I do not have enough rep).